# Get Min and Max Dates from SQL Server SQL

Tags: sql-server

Data in my table looks like this

```
PAY_END_DT  Sal
10/27/2013  0
11/10/2013  0
11/24/2013  2473.14
12/08/2013  0
01/19/2014  0
02/02/2014  0
02/16/2014  0
```

My desired result should be like as below

```
10/27/2013 11/10/2013
12/08/2013 02/16/2014
```

I need a SQL to generate this result set.. please help

Comment: Try replacing ***"I need a SQL"*** with ***"I have tried this SQL query and it did not work"***

Comment: and then "here's the query I tried using". This site is for programming **HELP**, not "do my job for me".

Comment: What differentiates the two rows in your answer set?

Comment: Your problem isn't well specified. It looks like you're trying to solve an "islands and gaps" style problem, but you didn't say why you're expecting that result in particular. What's the relation between input and output?

Comment: Explain the logic- I mean, to be precise - what did your boss ask you to do?

Comment: @Ravi Please be aware that dates in RDBMSs adhere to a specific format/data type.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the SQL. My output for the sql should be Employee ID, Start Date and End Date. In my data set, Employee 12345 did not receive Sal from 10/27/13 thru 11/10/2013 and then again from 12/08/13 to 02/26/14.. so, I am looking for output as follows: 12345 10/27/13 11/10/13 in the first row and 12345 12/08/13 02/26/14 in the second row. Hope this more info. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    MIN(pay_end_dt)   AS island_min_pay_end_dt,
    MAX(pay_end_dt)   AS island_max_pay_end_dt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        pay_end_dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id,
                               ORDER BY pay_end_dt   )     AS full_set_ordinal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, sal
                               ORDER BY pay_end_dt   )     AS zero_set_ordinal
    FROM
        yourTable
)
    AS sorted_set
WHERE
    sal = 0
GROUP BY
    employee_id,
    full_set_ordinal - zero_set_ordinal
;
```

Using your data as an example:

```
PAY_END_DT  Sal      FULL_SET_ORIDINAL  ZERO_SET_ORDINAL  "FULL - ZERO"
10/27/2013  0        1                  1                 0
11/10/2013  0        2                  2                 0
11/24/2013  2473.14  3                  1                 2
12/08/2013  0        4                  3                 1
01/19/2014  0        5                  4                 1
02/02/2014  0        6                  5                 1
02/16/2014  0        7                  6                 1
```

Which then allows us to include only the rows `WHERE sal = 0` and then `GROUP BY "FULL - ZERO"` to get our two sets, and then finally apply the `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions.

As stated in a comment, this is known as "Gaps and Islands".

```
    1 1 1   1   
0 0       0   0 0

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   - ordinal from the whole set

    1 2 3   4       - ordinal from just the "islands"
1 2       3   4 5   - ordinal from just the "gaps"

    2 2 2   3       - ordinal of the "islands"  (whole_set_id - islands_id)
0 0       3   4 4   - ordinal of the "gaps"     (whole_set_id - gaps_id)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the SQL. My output for the sql should be Employee ID, Start Date and End Date. In my data set, Employee 12345 did not receive Sal from 10/27/13 thru 11/10/2013 and then again from 12/08/13 to 02/26/14.. so, I am looking for output as follows: 12345 10/27/13 11/10/13 in the first row and 12345 12/08/13 02/26/14 in the second row. Hope this more info. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @Ravi - Then just add EmplyeeID to the GROUP BY and PARTITION BY clauses.

Comment: @Ravi - Please then could you vote for and accept the answer?

Answer (score -2):

;)

```
    SELECT "10/27/2013 11/10/2013"
    UNION  
    SELECT "12/08/2013 02/16/2014"
```

Comment: Good troll, but this is no place for trolling.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Personally, on the information provided, I consider this answer perfectly valid.

Comment: @Strawberry True, as I said, it's a good troll, but StackOverflow encourages honest and helpful answers. Btw, I did not downvote the answer.

Comment: @Strawberry - There is a world of difference between "technically correct" and "constructive or useful".  If something is not the latter then it has no place on StackOverflow.  *(And on that basis I suggest that it is not "perfectly valid"; as it fails to meet the explicit intention of SO Answers.)*

Comment: @MatBailie Perhaps we should strive to be both.